# PHP : Fixing server time (localhost)

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, timezone

For  my page when user  logs in  i've to save his  first login time , in my DB i've a field called loggedin,  and  in my login  function  i do this in query

```
set loggedin= now()
```

this saves something like  this   `2015-12-21 09:43:57`. now when user logs in again I've to   compare todays date with saved time in db to check  if there is already a  logged in entry for today,

but problem is that when i enter  time using NOW() it  enters my server time but when i try to make a  comparison by todays time

```
$today= time();
echo(date("Y-m-d",$today))
```

this shows me one day back i mean if its 21 today its showing  me  `2015-12-20`
so whats wrong with this ?

Comment: Try using UTC time `date_default_timezone_set("UTC");` for storing and comparing

Answer (score 0):

use `date_default_timezone_set`

```
date_default_timezone_set(your timezone);
$today= time();
echo(date("Y-m-d",$today))
```

Comment: I did this date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Dubai"); and then printed this  echo 'TIME'.date_default_timezone_get(); but that does not work

Comment: date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Dubai');
$today= time();
echo(date("Y-m-d",$today))

Answer (score 0):

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Dubai'); 
$today= time();
echo(date("d-m-Y",$today));
echo "<br>";
echo date("h:i:sa");
echo "<br>";
```

Try this code if it helps you.